# Using javascript, how to set a value to a number input that ends in decimal dot (ie. "100.")

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

### Setup

Suppose I have an input like this: `<input id="NumberInput" type="number" step="0.1" />`

As this is a number field, it will accept digits, minus sign and decimal dot. Thus, browsers allow me to type in "100." (note the decimal dot at the end). If I leave the input, the value will still remain the same and it will allow me to return and finish the number (ie. "100.1").

### Issue

I wasn't able to do this using JS in Chrome, as the following code:

```
document.getElementById('NumberInput').value = "100."
```

the input will be set to empty (regardless of the previous value) and the following error:

```
The specified value "100." cannot be parsed, or is out of range.`
```

I agree that this makes sense as "100." is by no means a valid number.

### Question

Is there any way around this, so I can populate the start of a number input with JS and allow user to insert only decimal value (or edit the whole number)?

I an guessing that when typing in "100.", Chrome internally stores this value as "100" but shows the dot so that the user can continue later. This is exactly what I need, only using JS.

### Notes

- I know that defining input as `type=text` will solve this, but would also create some problems (which are irrelevant to this question)
- Same error appears when using jQuery or any other JS library/framework
- I haven't tested this on any other browser, as failing in Chrome alone is a show-stopper

Thanks in advance, cheers!

Comment: Maybe setting the input to `type=text`, then adding value `100.` and then setting the type to `type=number` again works? I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're looking to accept non-number values (like "100.") I believe usage of `type="number"` is too specialized for you. I recommend you use `type="text"` and `pattern`, with a custom regex:

```css
input:invalid { background-color: #ffa0a0; }
```

```html
<input type="text" pattern="[1-9][0-9]*([.][0-9]?)?"/>
```

The pattern I used is:

```
[1-9][0-9]*([.][0-9]?)?

[1-9]                     any non-0 digit (since the leading digit shouldn't be 0)
     [0-9]*               any number of followup digits
           (         )?   a whole optional section
            [.]           a single "." character
               [0-9]?     an optional single digit
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. However, I need this to work in a JS framework, which does not use standard HTML form to submit data. Because HTML attribute "pattern" is applied only on form submit, it is unfortunately ignored by the application.

Comment: Which framework? You should tag your question accordingly - no one can give you a proper answer if we don't understand your situation

Comment: I am using Ember Octane. I thought that `javascript` tag would be enough :)

Comment: I don't know too much about ember octane - what exactly goes wrong if you switch your `<input>` to `type="text"`, and add the `pattern` attribute?

Comment: Nothing goes wrong,  it's that the `pattern` attributes gets completely ignored by the JavaScript. My initial idea is to turn to `type="text"` and use the regex like the one you explained within JavaScript, but I decided against it as it would add quite a bit of an overhead.